# Como pesquisar um trecho em um PDF remotamente?

Tags: php, pdf

Existe uma forma de eu pesquisar um trecho, ou uma palavra em um PDF que está na internet? Eu pesquisei sobre o CURL, algumas bibliotecas, mas não achei nada. Mais ou menos dessa forma:

Eu tenho um site e nele o cara inseriria um nome por exemplo: João. 
Após isso o script do meu site verificaria se dentro do arquivo: http://www.bu.ufsc.br/ArtigoCientifico.pdf existe o nome João, e me retornaria se existe ou não.

Tem como fazer isso? Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca ou pode me dar um norte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A biblioteca http://www.pdfparser.org/ permite pegar o texto de arquivos PDF.

```
$url = 'http://www.bu.ufsc.br/ArtigoCientifico.pdf';
$nome = 'João';

$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();

$pdf = $parser->parseContent(file_get_contents($url));
$text = $pdf->getText();

if (strpos($text, $nome) !== false) {
    // achou o nome
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, valeu cara!

Comment: Só mais uma duvida, vamos supor que eu eu tenho uma página, mas o link do PDF não está de forma clara nela, por exemplo: www.bu.ufsc.br/downloadArtigo.php?id=19898454 e somente ao clicar nesse link que o pdf é baixado. Se eu usar o file_get_contents funciona do mesmo jeito ou nao?

Comment: O file_get_contents funcionará do mesmo modo nesse caso, pois ele coleta o conteúdo sem se importar com a extensão.

Comment: Hmmm, entendi, muito obrigado o/

Comment: agora vou fazer uma outra pergunta, se tiver resposta eu crio a pergunta e você responde. Eu percebi que no site que o ID do download do PDF é gerado automaticamente, e eu não queria ter de inserir no sistema toda vez. Então existe alguma forma de eu colocar um file_get_content só com o link até o id= e ele baixar do mesmo jeito, alguma gambiarra do tipo?

Comment: No caso o id identifica qual documento baixar, você precisa saber o id, porém se houver uma página que contém um link para o artigo e não é uma página gerada dinamicamente por javascript, pode-se pegar o conteúdo usando `file_get_contents` na página com o link e achar o link com `preg_match` ou `preg_match_all` ou se for uma página muito complexa usando o https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: Puxa, isso seria o ideal, mas a maldita página usa JavaScript.

Comment: Já que a página é montada por javascript não conheço um modo de fazer com php, só conheço o http://casperjs.org/ em conjunto com http://phantomjs.org/ eles não são para php mas pode-se criar scripts deles e executar no php com funções como `exec`, porém sua hospedagem deve permitir adicionar e executar programas, o phantomjs é um programa base standalone sem interface gráfica que carrega páginas e executa o javascript, e o casperjs é um frontend para o phantomjs com facilidades para fazer as coisas.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada. Valeu!